# How to let JOptionPane accept integer but not String?

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, if-statement, joptionpane

I am trying to add validation to my code (as my brother puts it) and that it should only accept numbers and not letters as it moves through the array. I have tried different methods but it still accepts letters and if it doesn't it crashes at array[1].
here's the part of my code:

```
public static void main(String[]Terminal) {
String Choice;
char response1;
String response = null;
String Display = null;
String TryAgain = null;
String Element = null;
boolean Validation = true;

int numberOfElements = 5; //array element numbers
int index;
int Choice1;

int[] Array = new int[numberOfElements]; //array

do {    // Rewind Option
    do {
for (index = 0; index < numberOfElements; index++) { // Loop for Array Input

    if(index==0) //Dialog Design, tied to Loop

    {Element = "First";}    
    else if 
    (index==1) {Element = "Second";} 
    else if
    (index==2) {Element = "Third";}
    else if 
    (index==3) {Element = "Fourth";}
    else if 
    (index==4) {Element = "Fifth";}


    response = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the " + Element + " (" +(index+1)+ "): " ); //Display Dialog

// the validation should be here right?


}    
    int Array1 = Integer.parseInt(response);
    Array[index] = Array1;
```

Comment: What is the ultimate goal for this code? What are you trying to do?

Comment: For the Program to restrict the use of Strings and empty spaces for the input in JOptionPane. The User can Input Integer but should Show a message once a letter or an empty space is provided. While not compromising the array loop in anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you want to do but I'm not really sure what the ultimate purpose of your code is for. The reason I ask is that there may be a possibility that a ComboBox with a numerical list may be better suited for your InputBox dialog.

As you know your Input Box dialog will return a string. You need to ensure that what was entered was in fact a numerical value. To do this you can use the [String#matches()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm) method along with a [Regular Expression](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html), for example:

```
while(true) {
    //Display Dialog
    response = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the " + Element + 
                                           " (" +(index+1)+ "): " ); 
    if (!response.matches("\\d+") {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The data you entered is not a 
                                      valid Numerical Value (" + response + ").", 
                                      "Invalid Input", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        continue;
    }
    break;
}
```